# Which file will be executed in Win10?

Tags: windows-10

I have 2 files with similar names which are stored in folders in my PATH variable. Which of them will be executed? Can it be decided according to which if them will be listed 1st in the output of the where command?

Example:

```
(2gis) C:\Users\Kosh>where python
C:\Anaconda3\envs\2gis\python.exe
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

Comment: Short answer: The first one. Long answer: Read [Where - locate files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html). Very long answer: You are probably better using [Which.cmd - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-which.html) which returns the full path of the command that will be executed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 2 files with similar names which are stored in folders in my PATH variable. Which of them will be executed?

Typically, the one that appears first in your PATH. In your example (from the command line) that is:

```
C:\Anaconda3\envs\2gis\python.exe
```

Note, however, that some programs (such as Pycharm or even individual Python scripts via [shebangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))) may have their own methods of choosing what installation of an executable to use.

> Can it be decided according to which of them will be listed 1st in the output of the `where` command?

Likely only in cases where the program in question actually consults the Windows PATH.

---

*It's also probably worth mentiong that standard Python virtual environments generally only apply to the current command window. That is, they often must be activated separately in any new command window created.*

---